# How can I call Objective-C code (specifically code from Mac system libraries) from C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt

Also, what is the difference between a .m and a .mm file? Or is that just some convention that Nokia uses for Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.m refers to an Objective-C file, whereas .mm is an Objective-C++.  I'm not sure whose convention that is.

As for calling Objective-C from C++, this might help:

http://sseyod.blogspot.com/2009/02/objective-c.html